# How does one construct the Galois field extension $GF((2^2)^3)$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Looking at past exam question, one asks us to construct a Galois field extension $GF((2^2)^3)$ whenever the primitive irreducible polynomial $p(X) = X^3 + \alpha X^2 + \alpha X + \alpha \in GF(2^2)[X]$ is given. How do you answer this?

Comment: One usually also denotes the finite field of size $p^n$ by $\mathbb F_{p^n}$. Do you mean to construct $\mathbb F_{2^6}$ given an irreducible primitive cubic of the form above with $\alpha \in \mathbb F_{2^2}$?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I was typing the problem as was written, but yes what you wrote is what is meant.

Comment: And presumably, $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_{2^2}\setminus\mathbb{F}_{2}$?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Yes.

Comment: The construction should clearly be $GF((2^2)^3)=GF(2^2)[X]/\langle p(X)\rangle$. But otherwise whoever wrote down this question is a bit unclear. May be you are expected to verify that $p(X)$ really is a primitive polynomial? Because it's a cubic checking that it is irreducible is straightforward - it has no zeros in $GF(2^2)$. But we would still need to ascertain that $p(X)$ is not a factor of $x^{21}+1$ or $x^9+1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't think we're being asked to check if the polynomial is indeed primitive. I don't know very much yet, but I'm thinking the problem is to write down/find explicitly every element of the finite field as a linear combination of the basis elements of the corresponding cyclic group when, say, $\beta$ is the primitive element. I tried doing that and after very tedious computations wasn't able to show that $\beta^{63}=1$.

Comment: I was a bit worried that a teacher might mean that by "to construct". After all, for computer implementation having such a table at hand is a useful way of constructing the field. I guess I will post a few powers of $\beta$ as "checkpoints" for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It is easy to check that $p(X)$ is irreducible. Let $\beta$ be a zero of $p(X)$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\beta^3&=\alpha\beta^2+\alpha\beta+\alpha,\\
\beta^4&=\beta^2+\beta+\alpha^2,\\
\beta^5&=\alpha^2\beta^2+\beta+\alpha,\\
\beta^6&=\alpha^2\beta+1.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we can observe that $\beta^6+\beta^5+\beta^3=\beta^2+1$, so the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $GF(2)$ is $m(X)=X^6+X^5+X^3+X^2+1$.

At this point it is easy to cheat, fire up Mathematica, and check that $m(X)$ is not a factor of $x^{21}+1$. The only sextic factor of $X^9+1$ is $X^6+X^3+1$, so we now know that $\beta$ is of order 63, i.e. a primitive element.

Let's start squaring (using what we have calculated already) for a change to verify this
$$
\begin{aligned}
\beta^8&=(\beta^4)^2=\beta^4+\beta^2+\alpha^4&=\beta+1,\\
\beta^{16}&=(\beta^8)^2&=\beta^2+1,\\
\beta^{32}&=(\beta^{16})^2=\beta^4+1&=\beta^2+\beta+\alpha,\\
\beta^{64}&=(\beta^{32})^2=\beta^4+\beta^2+\alpha^2&=\beta.
\end{aligned}
$$
Well, well! There's a fair chance that no errors crept in, given that $\beta^{64}$ checks out.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have a question, why is it that $-1 = 1$, when I was doing the calculations by hand yesterday, I was using $-3=1$, and I had $\beta^3=3 \alpha \beta^2 + 3\alpha \beta + 3 \alpha$. Also, how do you find the inverse of $\alpha$, and then how exactly does $\beta^4= \beta^2 + \beta + \alpha^2$? If you can help with the relations of the elements in the coefficient field, then I think I'll be able to do the calculations.

Comment: $-1=1$ because we are in characteristic two. Remember that $GF(2^2)=\{0,1,\alpha,\alpha+1\}$ where $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$, and $1+1=0=\alpha+\alpha$. Consequently $\alpha^3=\alpha^2+\alpha=\alpha+1+\alpha=1.$

Comment: So
$$\beta^4=\beta\cdot\beta^3=\alpha\beta^3+\alpha\beta^2+\alpha\beta.$$
Here
$$\alpha\beta^3=\alpha^2\beta^2+\alpha^2\beta+\alpha^2,$$
so
$$
\beta^4=(\alpha+\alpha^2)\beta^2+(\alpha+\alpha^2)\beta+\alpha^2=
\beta^2+\beta+\alpha^2.$$